# How to fade out images and text(here text is associated to particular image) at a time using jQuery cycle plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

How to fade out images and text(here text is associated to particular image)  at a time using jQuery cycle plugin ?

```
<div>
<div id= "box-slider" class=" blueboxcontent " >
        <ul>
          <li>
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="news_instyle_c2p.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="text-warpper">
            <p>Some text here for image 1</p>
          </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="news_instyle3D.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text-warpper" >
            <p>Some text here for image 2</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="news_instyle.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text-warpper">
           <p>Some text here  for image 3 < /p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Script calling:

```
$( '#box-slider' ).cycle( { 
    fx:    'fade', 
    speed:  700,
    timeout:  2000
 });
```

CSS:

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

box-slider{
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

box-slider ul li {
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  height:102px;
  width: 396px;
}

box-slider ul li . img-wrapper {
  width:132px;
  float:left
}

box-slider ul li .text-warpper {
width:264px;
float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you only have one slide since cycle is applying to the div and you only have one 
Because cycle it applied the the direct child below on the dom structure.
Your selector should point to the  tag. Since it's not identified use the selection below
of give it a class or id and select it directly

A simple solution would be to change your selector.

```
$( '#box-slider ul' ).cycle( { 
  fx:    'fade', 
  speed:  700,
  timeout:  2000
});
```